# Creating a table if it doesn't exist (old versions of PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

In recent versions of postgreSQL one can use [the syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html):

```
create temp table if not exist my_table as 
...
```

to create a temporary table if it doesn't exist yet.

However, the clause `if not exist` is a relatively recent feature.

I am working against a database that uses PostgreSQL version 8.2.15. How can I create a temporary table if it doesn't exist yet?

Comment: Upgrade? Seriously, 8.2.15?

Answer (score 2):

The actual solution very much depends on your exact situation.  If you can use a `pl/pgsql` function, you can check first for the existence of the table:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'my_table')
THEN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_table ...
END IF;
```

You could also try to match the schema name (which will be something like `pg_temp*`) by joining the [`pg_namespace`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/catalog-pg-namespace.html) table to [`pg_class`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/catalog-pg-class.html).  Or use the [`pg_tables`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/view-pg-tables.html) view, which can be a bit easier.